# IWAB0399E Error use java -D

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, xsd, wsdl

I have a wsdl file that i imported to my project in Eclipse Kepler. Then i tried to generate a client in Kepler, but i kept getting this error.
I tried many solutions but nothing seemed to work. Now i found a new solution which is to use:

```
java -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost={value} -Dhttp.proxyPort={value} org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java {wsdlURL}
```

but where do i use this command and what are the values that i should give it?

```
IWAB0399E Error in generating Java from WSDL: 
     WSDLException (at /wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xsd:schema): 
faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: An error occurred trying to resolve schema referenced 
at 'Error.xsd', relative to 'file:/D:/home/eclipse_workspace/TEST/work
/gsi.wsdl'.: This file was not found: file:/D:/home/eclipse_workspace
/TEST/work/Error.xsd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file was not 
found: file:/D:/home/eclipse_workspace/TEST/work/Error.xsd
```

Any idea on how i solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like wsdl file has reference on Error.xsd file and WSDL2Java  tool didn't find it. This file was not found: file:/D:/home/eclipse_workspace/TEST/work/Error.xsd

Comment: @simar how can i solve this problem given that i don't have Error.xsd file ?

Comment: First try look into same source where wsdl was taken, or hard-way write you own Error.xsd and provide it to WSDL2Java.

Comment: What is the WSDL URL is it local file system or a server location. From the exception it seems to be local file system. In this case why do you need to set the proxy?